# Find a unit vector that maximizes the directional derivative at a point

Tags: calculus

Given the function

$f(x,y)=g(2x+y), g'(3)=3$

Find the coordinates of a unit vector $v=(v_1,v_2)$ that finds the maximum directional derivative $D_ uf(1,1)$ of f in the point $(1,1)$.

I know that I should find $\nabla f(x,y)*u$ in such a way that u maximizes it. But I am uncertain how to do so.

Comment: Hint: the directional derivative is maximized by selecting a vector parallel to the gradient

Comment: I found the gradient $f(1,1)=(6,3)$ Would dividing the gradient at the point over the length of the gradient at the point equal the max?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have given $y=g(t),\, \dfrac{dg}{dt}=g^\prime(t),\, g^\prime(3)=3,\,t=2x+y,\,f(x,y)=g(2x+y)$

Therefore, by the chain rule, $f_x(x,y)=\dfrac{dg}{dt}\cdot\dfrac{\partial t}{\partial x}=2g^\prime(t)$ and $f_y(x,y)=\dfrac{dg}{dt}\cdot\dfrac{\partial t}{\partial y}=g^\prime(t)$.

So $\nabla f(1,1)=\langle2,1\rangle g^\prime(t)=\langle2,1\rangle g^\prime(3)=\langle6,3\rangle$

$\vert \nabla f(1,1)\vert=3\sqrt{5}$, therefore $u=\dfrac{\nabla f(1,1)}{\vert \nabla f(1,1)\vert}=\left\langle \dfrac{2\sqrt{5}}{5},\dfrac{\sqrt{5}}{5}\right\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you. I believe I understand. Can you confirmed if this other example is correct.

Given $f(x,y)=g(4x+3y), g'(10)=-1$. The directional derivative at the point $(1,2)$ is $(-4,-6)$? And the max directional derivative would be $(-2sqrt(13)/13, -3sqrt(13)/13)$

Comment: The $(-4,-6)$ should be $\langle-4,-3\rangle$ since $f_x(x,y)=4g^\prime(t)$ and $f_y(x,y)=3g^\prime(t)$ with $t=4x+3y$. So $\nabla f=\langle4,3\rangle g^\prime(t)$. Thus, $\nabla(1,2)=\langle4,3\rangle g^\prime(10)=\langle-4,-3\rangle$. So $u=\langle-\frac{4}{5},-\frac{3}{5}\rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

note that the partial derivatives of $f(x,y)$ are:
$$
f_x=g' \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(2x+y)=2g' \qquad f_y=g' \frac{\partial}{\partial y}(2x+y)=g'
$$
so the gradient at $(1,1)$ is:
$$
\nabla f(x,y)= (2g'(3),g'(3))^T=(6,3)^T
$$

and, as noted in the comment, the directional derivative is maximized for a vector parallel to the gradient.

Comment: Yes....sorry. and thank you :)